# Override Objective-C class method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, overriding, jsonmodel

I'm trying to use JSONModel in a Swift project.
I would like to override the method keyMapper from JSONModel but I don't find how to override an Objective-C class method in the model class.

The signature of the method is:

```
+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: check JSONModel's readme here:https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel it says it's not tested with Swift

Comment: Yes I know but it doesn't mean it's not working. At the moment everything is working. I just would like to override this method to make some tests.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do it just like you override an instance method, except with the class keyword:

```
override class func keyMapper() -> JSONKeyMapper! {
    //code here
}
```